# current location in mapkit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

I have a mapkit view that data is being sent into from a previous view,  this works fine.  What I need to understand is how to set my source location to the current location of the user.  This is my lines of code code:

```
let sourcelocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: track.lat, longitude: track.lon)
let destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: track.lat, longitude: track.lon)
```

When I run, obviously this puts 2 pins in exactly the same location.

I'm not sure what to put in to the sourceLocation line to display current location.

I have the following lines in my code already:

var myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D

```
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

and I have declared my delegate with:

```
CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

Im just not sure where to go now.

Ultimately I am trying to get this to plot a route and allow you to navigate from your current location to the destination location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get current location coordinates by CLLocationManager as :

let sourcelocation = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using MapKit, you probably have a MapView implemented at some point. If it makes sense, you can use

```
mapView.userLocation.location
```

to get the location of the device.